# how to find any attributes with correlation more than 0.50

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, decision-tree

After analyzing the dataset, how can we find the correlation of all attributes?

```
correlations = data.corr(method='pearson')

print(correlation>=0.50)
```

I'm not getting the proper output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data:

```
import pprint
np.random.seed(4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((1000, 5)))
df.columns = list("ABCDE")
df_cor = df.corr(method='pearson')
```

df.head():

```
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.050562  0.499951 -0.995909  0.693599 -0.418302
1 -1.584577 -0.647707  0.598575  0.332250 -1.147477
2  0.618670 -0.087987  0.425072  0.332253 -1.156816
3  0.350997 -0.606887  1.546979  0.723342  0.046136
4 -0.982992  0.054433  0.159893 -1.208948  2.223360
```

df_cor:

```
          A         B         C         D         E
A  1.000000 -0.008658 -0.015977 -0.001219 -0.008043
B -0.008658  1.000000  0.037419 -0.055335  0.057751
C -0.015977  0.037419  1.000000  0.000049  0.057091
D -0.001219 -0.055335  0.000049  1.000000 -0.017879
E -0.008043  0.057751  0.057091 -0.017879  1.000000
```

```
# Checking for correlations > Absulute 0.05. Here i `0.05`, change it to `0.5` at your end.

df_cor[df_cor.abs() > .05].dropna(axis=1, how='all').replace(1., np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1).dropna(how='all', axis=0).apply(lambda x:x.dropna().to_dict() ,axis=1).to_dict()
```

```
{'B': {'D': -0.0553348494117175, 'E': 0.057751329924049855},
 'C': {'E': 0.057091148280687266},
 'D': {'B': -0.0553348494117175},
 'E': {'B': 0.057751329924049855, 'C': 0.057091148280687266}}
```

if you need dataframe output:

```
df_cor[df_cor.abs() > .05].replace(1, np.nan)
```

```
    A         B         C         D         E
A NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
B NaN       NaN       NaN -0.055335  0.057751
C NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.057091
D NaN -0.055335       NaN       NaN       NaN
E NaN  0.057751  0.057091       NaN       NaN
```

after dropping columns where is no value:

```
df_cor[df_cor.abs() > .05].replace(1, np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

```
          B         C         D         E
A       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
B       NaN       NaN -0.055335  0.057751
C       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.057091
D -0.055335       NaN       NaN       NaN
E  0.057751  0.057091       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: can you help me in performing 5 cross validation and to evaluate precision,recall and f1 scores in that model using decision tree